# Compare the stock price across different columns in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble to write lines of codes in R to look at the latest price of Stock A and compare it to the closing price of Stock A stored in a different column. Ideally, the code will look at Stock A,B,C,D,E and spits out the result based on the IF statement that I provide below.

Now my codes will compare four times instead of two times. I can't find a good way to re-write it. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
x<-c(2,4)

y<-c(3,5)


for(i in x) for(j in y){
  if (c[nrow(c),i]>c[nrow(c),j]){
    print("Ok")
  }else{
    print("no")
  }
}
```

Comment: "c" is the list of two stocks that I read in R. Just in case someone would be asking for clarification

Comment: Simply create an index and use only a single `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapply, previously spliting the Last and Close prices of the stocks in two diferent data frames:

```
Lista <- list("A_Last", "B_Last", "C_Last", "D_Last", "E_Last")
Lista2 <- list("A_Close", "B_Close", "C_Close", "D_Close", "E_Close")

lapply(Lista, function(x){
  assign(x, runif(10), envir = globalenv())
})

lapply(Lista2, function(x){
  assign(x, runif(10), envir = globalenv())
})

StockLast <- cbind.data.frame(A_Last, B_Last, C_Last, D_Last, E_Last)
StockClose <- cbind.data.frame(A_Close, B_Close, C_Close, D_Close, E_Close)

mapply(function(x, y) {
 if (x[[nrow(x)]] > y[[nrow(y)]]) {
   print("Ok")
 } else {
   print("no")
 }
}, x = StockLast, y = StockClose)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it shows the error message as follow  "Error in x[[nrow(x)]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index"

Comment: My mistake, nrow() in not defined for atomic vectors, lenght() must be used instead. I´ve change the example. Hope it works.